# lag with Ubuntu 16.0.4

Tags: gnome, dell

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.10 on an old desktop, a Dell Dimension 2400. I upgraded the ram from 512mb to 2gb, However Ubuntu is lagging horribly, I can barely use my PC. I tried lowering the swappiness rate to 1 but I am still lagging, I looked into the system monitor as suggested below, and the entirety of the processor, Intel 2.25ghz, dual core, is being used, and only half of the memory is being touched, any farther suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried using the system monitor application or `top` to see what's using the processor and memory?

Comment: I guess ubuntu with unity desktop is too much for a PC with 2GB RAM. Maybe you should try something lighter like lubuntu or xubuntu.

Comment: Did you try Lubuntu? Try it live without installing before you decide to install.

Answer (score 1):

I think this computer does not have enough cpu and graphics 'horsepower' for standard Ubuntu, but it should work with the ***light-weight*** flavour Lubuntu. I suggest that you try with ***Lubuntu 16.04.1 LTS 32-bit alias i386*** (it is important to get the 'first point release' (.1 at the end of the version number), otherwise you might have problems with the graphics. You find tips and also a general link to standard Ubuntu and all the community flavours via this link

[Try Ubuntu (Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, ...) before installing it](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389)